# How does the stat scaling on Ludwig's Holy Blade work?

Tags: bloodborne

I've got my Ludwig's Holy Blade up to +6, which says it scales B with Strength, C with Skill, and B with Arcane.

However, whenever I have the option to level up and I see what the affect would be of leveling up Arcane, it doesn't show an increase in weapon damage. It does, however, if I level up Strength or Skill.

Is it a bug that it says it scales with Arcane when it doesn't seem to, or am I missing something? And for this particular weapon, what's the best strategy for upgrading stats to maximize damage? Would I want to get Strength up first, and then Skill? If so, is there a soft cap on skills like Dark Souls had? What attributes should I be shooting for?

Comment: I wonder if it only affects magic damage (like when you put Gemstones on it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it a bug that it says it scales with Arcane when it doesn't seem
>   to, or am I missing something?

Arcane attack is needed for arcane scaling to work. Note that slotting arcane gems will change it to pure arcane weapon. Also buffs like fire paper and bolt paper do not scale.

> And for this particular weapon, what's the best strategy for upgrading
>   stats to maximize damage?

Good strategy is to uprade strength and skill equally. [This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bloodborne/comments/31hkzl/attribute_scaling_secrets_exposed_beasts_hate_him/) goes into detail about scaling. Basically upgrading to 25 gives the most percentage - 50% * base damage. Upgrading from 25 to 50 gives additional 35%. Scaling is linear in these ranges.

> What attributes should I be shooting for?

On my first playthrough I made a strength build and later regretted about it. The game basically wants you to upgrade everything a little bit to get max percentage bonuses. Upgrading vitality is essential because there are many situations where enemies hit for like 95% of your health and can easily one-shot you if you don't upgrade it.

Comment: Good advice. I've focused mainly strength and like you said it doesn't seem to be that great. I was actually thinking about making a question of my own about the Kirkhammer, as it seems to have non-obvious scaling behavior.

Comment: @originaluser I found that Kirkhammer is good from start to midgame. Skill scaling is bad so I had to find good gems to make it compelling. That stun effect on transformed attack makes it very good for combos if you have a lot of stamina or when fighting a bunch of enemies.

Comment: @user68854 So basically, ignore Arcane unless I'm going to gem it with arcane, in which case, I could instead ignore strength/skill, since they won't be used?

Comment: @Sterno for this particular weapon, yes.

Comment: @Sterno Convert it to bolt/fire weapon via gems if you know enemy weaknesses well and difference between kin and beast - you will have to dig into the lore which is rather alien.

Answer (score 0):

so when you level up arcane on Ludwig holy blade it's only referring too the damage by fire paper or bolt paper that's why it dont show in you damage on my opinion it's better too put most skills into more useful skills like strength and skill
Because those are the skills there refer too damage on the weapon itself

Comment: Hi Jeremy, please use proper punctuation and put some more effort into your answer altogether. We try to maintain a high quality site here :) Also be sure to check existing answers to see if yours actually adds anything new. Welcome to Arqade!